# how to check if the sum of digits is divisible by this sum?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to calculate the sum of the digits of a user-specified number first. Then I want to check if this number is divisible by the sum of its digits. Unfortunately, for example, for 21 it shows that it is not divisible, and for 200 that it is divisible. Maybe someone helps me. I'm just learning the language pl SQL.

```js
DECLARE 
    
    n   number(5):=&give_number;  
    temp_sum INTEGER;  
    r        INTEGER;
    a varchar(20);
BEGIN 
    temp_sum := 0;  
  

    WHILE n <> 0 LOOP  
        r := MOD(n, 10);  
        temp_sum := temp_sum + r;  
        n := Trunc(n / 10);  
    END LOOP;   
    a:=mod(r,temp_sum);
    if a = 0   then
    dbms_output.put_line('Divisible');
    else
    dbms_output.put_line('No divisible');
    end if;
END;
```

Comment: The data type of variable `a` is `varchar`. Is that correct? Shouldn't it be `number`?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `r` is divisible by `temp_sum` and, if you consider what values they are holding then `r` is the most-significant digit and `temp_sum` is the digit sum. Which for an input of `21` checks whether `2` (the most-significant digit) is exactly divisible by `3`, which it correctly reports that it is not divisible.

To fix it, you want to keep the input number in a variable that you do not modify and use that in the final comparison and not `r`:

If we remove some of the unnecessary variables and give the others more meaningful names:

```sql
DECLARE 
    input_value     NUMBER(5) := &give_number;
    remainder_value NUMBER(5) := input_value;
    digit_sum       INTEGER;  
BEGIN 
    digit_sum := 0;  

    WHILE remainder_value <> 0 LOOP 
        digit_sum := digit_sum + MOD(remainder_value, 10);
        remainder_value := TRUNC(remainder_value / 10);
    END LOOP;  
    dbms_output.Put_line(remainder_value);  
    dbms_output.Put_line('sum of digits = ' || digit_sum);  

    IF MOD(input_value,digit_sum) = 0   then
      dbms_output.put_line('Divisible');
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('Not divisible');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Then when you put in `21` the output is:

> ```
> 0
> sum of digits = 3
> Divisible
> ```

And for `202`, the output is:

> ```
> 0
> sum of digits = 4
> Not Divisible
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc5fdaf89574847dafcc35ac50b089f0)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more compact way to write your PL/SQL block, using some of the features specific to the language. Perhaps the most interesting one is the nesting of program units (subroutines) - something that, in C for example, is not permitted. I am referring to the declaration and full code of a "helper function" (the sum of digits function) right in the `DECLARE` section of the outer block.

The function also demonstrates a compact way to write the function recursively. In this case recursion isn't too deep (only as many recursive calls as there are digits in the input number); in general, if you can write the same function using a loop, as you did, instead of using recursion, is preferred - far less overhead. On the other hand, with the proper settings (an advanced topic), the interpreter will inline the recursive calls - essentially converting the recursive function to a simple loop. That way you can have the best of both worlds: clean, compact code, yet efficient interpreted code and execution.

I also show the more compact way to display your output to the screen. You only need one call to `put_line`; let the "if" (or "case expression") take care of what is to be displayed *within* the `put_line` call. Moreover, the common part, `'Divisible'`, can be factored out; the `case` expression simply adds `'Not '` when it's needed.

```
declare

  n number := &input_number;

  function sum_of_digits(n integer) return integer is
  begin
    return mod(n, 10) + case when n < 10 then 0
                             else sum_of_digits(trunc(n/10)) end;
  end;

begin
  dbms_output.put_line(
    case when mod(n, sum_of_digits(n)) != 0 then 'Not' end || 'Divisible');
end;
/
```

Notice one more thing: the outer block has a variable called `n`, but the function (in the `declare` section) also has a variable `n`. For the duration of the nested block (the function definition), `n` means the local variable. You need to always pay attention to such "masking" of an outer variable by a local variable by the same name.